# how can i make a small text apear when the cursor hovers over a component in java

Tags: java, swing, text, cursor, tooltip

Is there a way to make a  text appear beside the cursor when the cursor hovers over a component in my JFrame? I want to display something like a side note.

For instance, when the cursor enters a Jpanel the text reads "this is a panel" and it follows the cursor. I tried to be specific...sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You mean like a `tooltip`? Have a look at [How to Use Tool Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)

Comment: Yes Exactly this was what i needed, thank you!